# Code formatting Visual Studio Code - Line Length

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I've been working with Visual Studio Code for a while. Since yesterday the code formatting is not working as I expect but I haven't changed any configuration.

This is the file without formatting

[image: Code without formatting]

[image: Code without formatting]

When it gets formatted:

[image: Code formatted]
[image: Code formatted]

These are the settings modified by me

[image]

What can I do form improving this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is not TypeScript or VSCode doing this.

You have the prettier extension installed. Prettier will always do this, as [prettier knows better](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEBLAtgBwgJxgAmAEMBnAEwDNTLqryKAaW5+2p1jm+9r3uynvyFsWfNgF98FHBHT4AOiAoQIigNwgGICJhipoJZKCI4ZAdwAKJhIZREAbhFRlNIAEY4iYANZwYAZUwvVCgAc2QYHABXOC0ACxh0ABsAdTjUeBIgsDh-GwzUewyAT2RwEkMtEJI4PAtPUPQiZCokmq0AKxIADwAhTx8-fyJ0OAAZELgWojbYkC7u-xDQpLgARSiIeGnZrSCcGpwytyI3YqToV0wcEJgU5xg45AAOAAY9mRqUz0wy67hDvYplocHAAI5RVCg+pERrNJCtdogGroVARaJzEjLVYbLZTBEzJEwU73MiPZAAJi0kSIqCSywAwrImmUoNBgSAojUACqnWyIuDicRAA)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I chaged "Prettier:Print Width" setting and it worked

Comment: what if I don't have prettier?

Comment: @johnk You can use in settings.json of VSCode this configuration `"editor.rulers": [80, 120],`

Answer (score 36):

Open Extensions on the menu on the left or File menu.

Then click on the extension settings button.

Change the line length for the extension you are working with.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

#### I had to create a `.prettierrc` file and set it up like this:

[image: Prettier vscode configuration file line length]

Here is a copiable version :)

```json
{
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "useTabs": false,
  "printWidth": 120
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using **Prettier** extension, you can set the property **printWidth** from the *settings.json* file in VS Code:

`"prettier.printWidth": 71`

You can select the width according to the column selection, shown in the status bar.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have a background in `PyCharm` and because i had been doing a lot of `PHP` programming, ended up using VS Code a lot.

So, when i returned to `Python`, i realised `vs code` has terrible formatting for `Python` code.

**This is how i set up my vertical PEP8 79 character ruler in Vs Code.**

1. List item

Open `Settings.json` file
Press `Ctrl + Shift + P` to open Command Palette and there type "`Open Settings (JSON)`" and select `Preferences: Open Default Settings (JSON)` from the list. This will open a `Setings.json` file.

2. List item

Add the ruler's settings as shown below.

```
"editor.rulers": [ 79 ]
```

3 Close VS Code and Reopen it.

Vertical lines now appear at the 79th PEP8 character length.

If you want to increase characters like 80 or anything else then just replace 79 with any integer number.

Goodluck

Comment: the default formater for python on vscode seems to be autopep8, using black tool.
This article better describes how to change the settings of the line length:
https://dev.to/adamlombard/vscode-setting-line-lengths-in-the-black-python-code-formatter-1g62

Answer (score 0):

## C# and csharpier extension

Create a new file named `.csharpierrc.json` in the main directory of your project. And edit the `printWidth` parameter as you wish.

```
{
    "printWidth": 100,
    "useTabs": false,
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "preprocessorSymbolSets": ["", "DEBUG", "DEBUG,CODE_STYLE"]
}
```

Source: [here](https://csharpier.com/docs/Configuration)