# Vscode - How to change max line value about "organizeImports"?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I use vscode for python.

I want to set the max line length to 120 and to use `source.organizeImports` as an option.

But, the import line checked max line length is 80.

How to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Code formatting Visual Studio Code - Line Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253523/code-formatting-visual-studio-code-line-length)

Comment: I find solve. organizeImports limit length regard `sortimports`.
So, This option is answer of my question.

"python.sortImports.args": [ "-ns", "__init__.py", "-l", "120" ],